# Jquery onfocus / onchange events

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu which keeps track of the previous and current selected element. The dropdown default value starts on {0}. When a user changes the dropdown the new_value is stored say {2}, but the previous is always {0} unless the user clicks off the dropdown and then re-focuses on a new value, then the previous updates to that value in this case {2}.

Is there a way I can force the focus to update even if the user never un-focuses the dropdown box, basically on every change event?

```
(function () {
var previous;

    $('select[name=item_a]').focus(function () {
        previous = parseInt($(this).val()); }).change(function() {

            var new_value = $(this).attr('id'); 

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var previous, new_value;

$('select[name=item_a]').on({

   focus: function(){
      previous = parseInt($(this).val());
   },

   change: function(){
        new_value = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).blur();
   }

 });
```

Comment: Is there a way I can simply deselect the drop-down box after every change event, so it forces it to get a new focus?

Comment: You can trigger a .blur() event

Comment: If you set up your change event properly you shouldn't need to un-focus you element.

Comment: @zshooter That is true, yet it looks like the OP is looking for different information depending on whether its focused or changed.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the focus, you can call:

```
$('select[name=item_a]').trigger('focus')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$("input").on("focus", function(e) {
your code
});

$("input").on("change", function(e) {
your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should set your value when you change:

```
var previous, current;

$('#select[name=item_a]').change(
    previous = current;
    current = $('#select[name=item_a]').val();
);
```

also I'ld suggest setting the id of the select so you can do `$('#selectId')` instead of `$('select[name=item_a]')` it is going to have better performance, and your JQuery selectors will be easier to read.